# Filter inside nested ComplexTypes

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to filter based upon the value of tagdata/tags/tag. Any ideas for me? Basically I just want to select documents where the text of the tag matches a specific string. Thanks!

The filter:

```
search=*&$filter=tagdata/tags/any(tag: tagdata/tags/tag eq 'text1')
```

The error:

```
Invalid expression: The parent value for a property access of a property 'tag' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.
```

I've got a ComplexType definition that looks like this:

```
{
      "name": "tagdata",
      "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
      "analyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "tags",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
          "analyzer": null,
          "synonymMaps": [],
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "tagid",
              "type": "Edm.Int64",
              "facetable": false,
              "filterable": true,
              "retrievable": true,
              "sortable": false,
              "analyzer": null,
              "indexAnalyzer": null,
              "searchAnalyzer": null,
              "synonymMaps": [],
              "fields": []
            },
            {
              "name": "tag",
              "type": "Edm.String",
              "facetable": true,
              "filterable": true,
              "key": false,
              "retrievable": true,
              "searchable": true,
              "sortable": false,
              "analyzer": "en.lucene",
              "indexAnalyzer": null,
              "searchAnalyzer": null,
              "synonymMaps": [],
              "fields": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "tagid": 83,
      "tag": "text1"
    },
    {
      "tagid": 29,
      "tag": "text2"
    },
    {
      "tagid": 69,
      "tag": "text3"
    },
    {
      "tagid": 115,
      "tag": "text4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
search=*&$filter=tagdata/tags/any(t: t/tag eq 'text1')
```

Think of the `any` lambda expression as a loop over the `tags` collection, where the identifier behind the colon is the loop variable. That variable is of complex type, so you can access its properties using a slash.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bruce, this is very helpful! Worked like a champ! Very happy with Azure Cognitive search, overall.